code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error after upgrading playwright version
I am creating automated test suite using Cucumber, Java and Playwright, nameley I used this template github.com/akshayp7/playwright-java-cucumber.
After updating playwright to latest in pom.xml file, all the scenarios still execute as expected but at the end I can see the following error log in the console:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module './../../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\utils\userAgent.js
- C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\utils\index.js
- C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\cli\programWithTestStub.js
- C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at getPlaywrightVersion (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\utils\userAgent.js:91:54)
    at HarTracer.stop (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\server\har\harTracer.js:414:54)
    at Tracing.abort (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\server\trace\recorder\tracing.js:204:21)
    at CRBrowserContext._didCloseInternal (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\server\browserContext.js:191:18)
    at CRBrowserContext._browserClosed (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\server\browserContext.js:183:10)
    at CRBrowser._didClose (C:\Users\ADAMMY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\package\lib\server\browser.js:109:52) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\ADAMMY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\\package\\lib\\utils\\userAgent.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ADAMMY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\\package\\lib\\utils\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ADAMMY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\\package\\lib\\cli\\programWithTestStub.js',
    'C:\\Users\\ADAMMY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\playwright-java-8660868693867797388\\package\\cli.js'
  ]
}

I'm not very familiar with npm and looking at solutions for similar questions, they say to reinstall the cjs module or npm completeley. This obviosuly doesn't work as these are not the problem, nor do I know where to download modules in error from. I assume this is handled by IntelliJ but I have no idea how to go about this. I am also unsure where the is the ./../../package.json' that npm is looking for as not sure from what level it has been called. Also the playwright-java-8660868693867797388 folder contains only node.exe file


Selecting these options for cache invalidation and restarting the IDE twice has solved the issue

Did not work for me
